# In inherited search view field not found

Tags: odoo-15

First I Inherit hr.employee model in my custom module and add a field unique_id. Than in my custom module I inherit hr.employee search view for this unique_id field. But throw this error,  Field "unique_id " does not exist in model "hr.employee"

```
Here is python file:

class HrUniqueId(models.Model):
    _inherit = "hr.employee"

    unique_id = fields.Char(string='ID', required=True, copy=False, readonly=True,
                            default=lambda self: _('New'))
Here is XMLfile:
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="hr_employee_search_inherit">
            <field name="name">hr.employee.search.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
             <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_filter"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                 <xpath expr="//search" position="inside">
                     <field name="unique_id" string="Employee Id"/>
                 </xpath>
            </field>
         </record>

Error massage is:
<search string="Employees">
                    <field name="name" string="Employee" filter_domain="['|', ('work_email', 'ilike', self), ('name', 'ilike', self)]"/>
                    <field name="category_ids" groups="hr.group_hr_user"/>
                    <field name="job_id"/>
                    <separator/>

Field "unique_id" does not exist in model "hr.employee"

View error context:
{'file': 'c:\\odoo\\fornew\\fornew\\odoo\\custom\\employee_details\\views\\employee_details.xml',
 'line': 3,
 'name': 'hr.employee.search.inherit',
 'view': ir.ui.view(2023,),
 'view.model': 'hr.employee',
 'view.parent': ir.ui.view(366,),
 'xmlid': 'hr_employee_search_inherit'}
```

Comment: add groups="hr.group_hr_user" in the field like `unique_id = fields.Char(string='ID', required=True, copy=False, readonly=True,groups="hr.group_hr_user",
                            default=lambda self: _('New'))`